# Channel communication behaviour with select statement in goroutines

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

This is a modified version of the one provided by ["A Tour of Go"](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
            fmt.Println("GEN", x)
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println("DISP", <-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

Here is the output for the above code:

```
DISP 0
GEN 1
GEN 1
DISP 1
DISP 1
GEN 2
GEN 3
DISP 2
DISP 3
GEN 5
GEN 8
DISP 5
DISP 8
GEN 13
GEN 21
DISP 13
DISP 21
GEN 34
GEN 55
DISP 34
quit
```

I don't understand the behaviour of the code. Why are 2 Fibonacci numbers generated before displaying both of them? Does this depend on the execution environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the receiver in goroutine (`go func() {...}`) executes concurrently when receives value from sender (select statement in `func fibonacci()`).

By adding a delay after send a value (`c <- x:`) will avoid multipe sending at the same time so you can see more clearly.
Try this code: (https://play.golang.org/p/9rOdS2YThKR)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        fmt.Println("-----------------------------------------")
        fmt.Println("current x:", x)
        select {
        //Send a value into a channel using the c <- x syntax, block until receiver is ready
        case c <- x:
            //When receiver gets x value, this code will executes
            //Delay, avoid mutilple sending at the same time
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)
            //Increase
            x, y = y, x+y
            fmt.Println("increased x to", x)
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        //The <-c syntax receives a value from the channel, block until sender is ready
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println("received x:", <-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

Result for above code is:

```
-----------------------------------------
current x: 0
received x: 0
increased x to 1
-----------------------------------------
current x: 1
received x: 1
increased x to 1
-----------------------------------------
current x: 1
received x: 1
increased x to 2
-----------------------------------------
current x: 2
received x: 2
increased x to 3
-----------------------------------------
current x: 3
received x: 3
increased x to 5
-----------------------------------------
current x: 5
received x: 5
increased x to 8
-----------------------------------------
current x: 8
received x: 8
increased x to 13
-----------------------------------------
current x: 13
received x: 13
increased x to 21
-----------------------------------------
current x: 21
received x: 21
increased x to 34
-----------------------------------------
current x: 34
received x: 34
increased x to 55
-----------------------------------------
current x: 55
quit
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to how goroutines are scheduled by the runtime. Firstly by adding a delay after each push to channel c, we get correct result as shown below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
            x, y = y, x+y
            fmt.Println("GEN", x)
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println("DISP", <-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

Result for above code is:

```
DISP 0
GEN 1
DISP 1
GEN 1
DISP 1
GEN 2
DISP 2
GEN 3
DISP 3
GEN 5
DISP 5
GEN 8
DISP 8
GEN 13
DISP 13
GEN 21
DISP 21
GEN 34
DISP 34
GEN 55
quit
```

Go Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/QD5kyGXWoJk

By adding a delay after every send on channel c, we are invoking the goroutine scheduler to put current goroutine on the wait queue, thus allowing the other goroutine is scheduled and successfully prints the message. Golang has cooperative scheduling, so goroutines are not preempted immediately.